# How do i fix this return compilation error?

Tags: java

Getting the following error and I'm not sure how to solve it:

```
    This method must return a result of type String
```

Program is supposed to print all lines of the file "months.txt" when "String result = fileRead(0, "months.txt");" = 0. It works without the huge if-else when I specify a line to be output but I can't figure out how to get it to work like this,

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class methodsExceptions1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String result = fileRead(0, "months.txt");
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static String fileRead(int line, String f) throws IOException {

        File myFile = new File("months.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);

        if (line == 0 && inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(inputFile.nextLine());
        } else {
            String lineRead = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < line; i++) {
                if (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
                    lineRead = inputFile.nextLine();
                } else {
                    return "FILE READ ERROR: There are only " + i + " lines of text in this file";
                }
        }
        inputFile.close();

        return lineRead;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you format your code properly with good indentation, I think it will become apparent that not all paths return a value.

Comment: It looks like you're undecided on whether you want to print the line or return it..

Comment: Why passing argument ```String f``` if you don't use it?

Comment: When the method is 0 its supposed to use the first if otherwise it should use the else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method only returns a string in the `else` branch. If `line == 0 && inputFile.hasNextLine()` is true, nothing is returned.

To fix the error, return something in your positive branch, or throw an exception.

Maybe you intended to return `inputFile.nextLine()` instead of printing it.

Comment: Yes! That has fixed it thank you, though it is only outputting the first line of the txt file whereas i want it to output the entire contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your `return` statement inside if or if-else or else block, then you will get this type of error.

So, you should also write a `return` statement out of these blocks. (also, some editors will block this code during coding)

```
public class MethodsExceptions1 {
     ...
     ...
     public static String fileRead(int line, String f) throws IOException {

        File myFile = new File("months.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);


        if(line == 0 && inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(inputFile.nextLine());
        }else {
            String lineRead = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < line; i++) {

                if (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {

                    lineRead = inputFile.nextLine();

                } else {

                    return "FILE READ ERROR: There are only " + i + " lines of text in this file";

                }

            }
            inputFile.close();

            return lineRead;
        }
       
        //need a return statement here
        return new String("");
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you, that has worked though it is only printing out the first line of the txt file and it should be printing the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is a liar. By its signature, you would expect it to read something from a file and return it as a String object. But in one case it returns nothing and prints something to the console. He's lying to you. Avoid side effects in your methods.

You can improve this if your method only returns a String. Let the caller of your method decide whether this String should be printed.

Instead of

```
if (line == 0 && inputFile.hasNextLine())
    System.out.println(inputFile.nextLine());
```

do

```
if (line == 0 && inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
    return inputFile.nextLine();
```

Comment: Yes that has worked although it is only print out the first line of the txt file and it should be printing the entire file.

Comment: In such a case, let your method return null after printing the line. And it should definitely have a different name that reflects its side effect. This is bad practice.